# Integrating Source Code into a Visual Studio Project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, nuget

I'm using a NuGet package called Hangfire in my VS project. However I'd like to be able to step thru each Hangfire API which is not possible as these files are under the "References" folder, so I've downloaded a copy of the Hangfire source code from Github. However, how do I integrate this code into an existing Visual Studios Project? Or maybe even simpler, instead of installing a NuGet Package, how do I reference the methods in the HangFire source code in my VS Project?

Answer (score 3):

In order to reference these files, you'll need to...

- Add the Hangfire project (or projects!) into your Solution. This can be done by right-click -> `add existing Project` on the solution.
- Make sure that you're referencing the Hangfire in the Solution. This can be ensured by removing all references, and then readding them, making sure to draw from the `Solution` section in the `Add Reference` dialog.
- Make sure the Hangfire projects are set to build in the dependant configurations. This can be done by selecting the `Configuration Manager` either in Solution settings or via the configuration or platform drop-down. Make sure the Hangfire projects are checked for any configuration/platform combinationin which your projects are selected

Assuming you have a repo for you project (and you always should), you may also be able to embed Hangfire as a subrepo in your repo, so updating and keeping versions synced is easier.

Comment: I'm having trouble referencing the "assembly name/default namespace" of the Hangfire files I've imported. For example, one of the names is "Hangfire.Core" I tried "using Hangfire.Core", however, it's not seeing "Core"

Comment: In order to reference the namespace, you need to make sure that you're referencing the project, and that it's been built. I'll update my answer with a checklist on this

Comment: When I attempted to build each of the 4 Hangfire src projects. I got, for each project:   Error 2 This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Enable NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is C:\Users\Jerry_Dev\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Hangfire.Highlighter\\.nuget\NuGet.targets. C:\Users\Jerry_Dev\Documents\GitHub\Hangfire\src\Hangfire.Core\Hangfire.Core.csproj 454 5 Hangfire.Core

Comment: I tried to do a NuGet Package Restore, as directed here:  http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/package-restore. But it could not recognize "nuget" as a command either in the Windows cmd, or Package Manager

Comment: NuGet package restore means the NuGet references are still in place - you'll need to actively uninstallthe packages via the NuGet interface, since you're replacing those references with the subprojects

Comment: Uninstall the packages from which projects? What commands? These NuGet Package restore errors are for each of my 4 Hangfire src projects, not for my Web App that will eventually be using methods from these src projects.

Comment: Then restore NuGet packafges on Hangfire - they seem to be reliant on some packages of their own, and angry about it!

Comment: nuget.exe : The term 'nuget.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling 
of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

Comment: Tried "nuget.exe restore" in Package Manager and Windows cmd, same type of error